# App Crashing when calling New Activity Intent from Webview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, webview, nullpointerexception

I'm developing app to load PDF file into new PDF activity from Webview
using intent & **PdfViewer.jar** library. I know it is not possible to open PDF files in Webview but trying to open in **activity_pdf.xml**
When i click link in Webview my App fails to call PdfViewer.class & Crashing, What can be the possible cause. Please help I'm stuck here.
Code looks fine no errors.

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PdfActivity.this,PdfViewer.class);
            final Uri uri = PdfActivity.this.getIntent().getData();
            URL pdfurl = null;

            try {
                pdfurl = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            intent.putExtra("PDFURL", pdfurl);
            startActivity(intent);
            System.out.println("PDF WORKING");

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```

Refer my Logcat error

```
2022-01-19 04:17:12.401 22159-22159/ak.wp.meto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ak.wp.meto, PID: 22159
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
        at ak.wp.meto.activity.PdfActivity$MyWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(PdfActivity.java:90)
        at android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewClient.java:83)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Unknown Source:90)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

What can be the error in this line? I'm getting logcat error on this line. Please help

```
        pdfurl = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
```

I'm using PdfViewer.jar library, In README text it is mentioned use, See below link for your reference,
https://sourceforge.net/p/andpdf/code/HEAD/tree/tag/Beta_0_1_11/AndroidPdfViewer/activitysrc/net/sf/andpdf/

Comment: I have some doubts in your code how do you map the link is an pdf to restart the activity?

Answer (score 1):

1. From where you getting the uri.
2. It clearly show that uri is null means have no value.
3. if you are getting it from previous activity use this.

   ```
     final Uri uri= getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your uri (`Uri uri = PdfActivity.this.getIntent().getData();`)
variable does not get data from intent. so you need to get data first for that use  `final Uri uri= getIntent().getStringExtra("name");` as @Manjeetdeswal answered

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Intent intent;
URL pdfurl = null;
if( PdfActivity.this.getIntent().getStringExtra("your key")!=null){
            final Uri uri = PdfActivity.this.getIntent().getData();
            try {
                pdfurl = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
if(/*check the URL is pdf contained URL*/){// check with url(String)
            intent = new Intent(PdfActivity.this,PdfViewer.class);
            intent.putExtra("PDFURL", pdfurl);
            startActivity(intent);
            System.out.println("PDF WORKING");
}
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```

check the pdf is contained in the URL then pass the URL to another activity

Answer (score 0):

Just move the start intent code into the try catch. Only if pdfurl is present start the new activity or show error.

```
 public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PdfActivity.this,PdfViewer.class);
        final Uri uri = PdfActivity.this.getIntent().getData();
        URL pdfurl = null;

        try {
            pdfurl = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
```

intent.putExtra("PDFURL", pdfurl);
startActivity(intent);
System.out.println("PDF WORKING");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

```
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```